# How to run a specific job in gitlab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are facing a problem where we need to run one specific job in gitlab CI. We currently not know how to solve this problem. We have multitple jobs defined in our `.gitlab-ci.yml` but we only need to run a single job within our pipelines. How could we just run one job e.g. `job1` or `job2`? We can't use `tags` or `branches` as a software switch in our environment.

#### .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
before_script:
  - docker info

job1:
  script:
    - do something

job2:
  script:
    - do something
```

Comment: do you find the solution? I have similar situation, I only need an environment cleanup job be triggered by the schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### > Currently it seems not to be possible with GitLab CI to have other software switches than `tags` or `branches` as provided in the other answers.

We finally switched to an other "real" CI due to too many limitations on GitLab CI. GitLab CI is unfelixble if you want to run some custom jobs in different procedures. I realy appreciated the both answers here. I'm sure they will help other users to manage this stuff. Unfortunately in our case we could not use `tags`, `commit messages` or `branches` as a software switch.

We are still looking for a answer on this. Feel free to give an other approach to solve this problem. I will mark the right answer once it hits. Also a bounty on this question did not result in an right answer.

Comment: Agree, I find gitlab CI confusing, complicated not flexible.  What are you using actually ? Is there a way to write build in procedural like way ?

Comment: @PavelNiedoba Bamboo, TeamCity CI or Jenkins are much nicer!

Comment: This is possible with GitLab CI. Please see my answer below for details

Comment: @lin Please consider updating the accepted answer as while this might have been the case when you asked the question, it is no longer the case. For people coming across this now and in the future, it would be ideal to have the correct answer accepted here.

Comment: Yeah this accepted answer is a bit limiting. Things have changed so maybe a solution is now available besides "not possible" Also in the original post there is no information of how you DO expect to send "switch" information, just that you can't use branch or tag.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a [gitlab variable expression](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#variables-expressions) with only/except like below and then pass the variable into the pipeline execution as needed.

This example defaults to running both jobs, but if passed 'true' for "firstJobOnly" it only runs the first job.

**Old Approach** -- *(still valid as of gitlab 13.8)* - [only/except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept)

```
variables:
  firstJobOnly: 'false'

before_script:
  - docker info

job1:
  script:
    - do something

job2:
  script:
    - do something
  except:
    variables:
      - $firstJobOnly =~ /true/i
```

**Updated Approach** - [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)

While the above still works, the best way to accomplish this now would be using the [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) syntax. A simple example similar to my original reply is below.

If you explore the options in the rules syntax, depending on the specific project constraints there are many ways this could be achieved.

```
variables:
  firstJobOnly: 'false'

job1:
  script: 
    - do something

job2:
  script: 
    - do something
  rules:
    - if: '$firstJobOnly == "true"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

Comment: I believe this wasn't possible when this question was first asked, but this is possible and how this is done now.    +1 on this answer, this should be the accepted answer now  :P

Answer (score 9):

We faced the same problem in the past and I'm sharing with you our solution.

#Remark#

- I read the answer of *Jawad* and I found it good and we have tried it when we faced the issue.
- My remark is that adding `when: manual` will always show ALL your jobs in the pipeline.
- So if you work in a large team, you can't prevent other collaborators to click by error or by mistake on the job you don't want to be launched.

#What I'm supposing before continuing#

- Let's say that you have 4 jobs.
- You need to always run (manually or automatically) `job 1`, `job 2` and `job 4` but NOT `job3`.
- You want to only run `job 3` in a specific case or just when you decide to run it.

#The idea is#

- We launch the 3rd job only for tags which match a regular expression.
- In the example below, it's launched for tags like `helloTag.1`, `helloTag.2`, `helloTag.3`... etc.
- If we are in `develop` or `master` (or other branch), we will have 3 stages (stage 1, stage 2, stage 4)

  **Note how the 3rd job is not present in the pipeline**

  [image]
- Go to "Repository" --> "Tags" --> "New tag"

  **Give the tag a name which much your regular expression**

  [image]
- If we are in a tag having a name which starts with "helloTag.", we will have 1 stage (stage 3)

  **Note how other stages are not present here**

  [image]

#Example of `.gitlab-ci` file#

```
stages:
    - myStage1
    - myStage2
    - myStage3
    - myStage4

This is my first stage:
    stage: myStage1
    before_script:
        - echo "my stage 1 before script"
    script:
         - echo "my stage 1 script"
    except:
        - /^helloTag.*$/

This is my second stage:
    stage: myStage2
    before_script:
        - echo "my stage 2 before script"
    script:
         - echo "my stage 2 script"
    except:
        - /^helloTag.*$/

This is my third stage:
    stage: myStage3
    before_script:
        - echo "my stage 3 before script"
    script:
         - echo "my stage 3 script"
    only:
        - /^helloTag.*$/

This is my fourth stage:
    stage: myStage4
    before_script:
        - echo "my stage 4 before script"
    script:
         - echo "my stage 4 script"
    except:
        - /^helloTag.*$/
```

Hope that this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. This will help some users, thats for sure. Unfortunately this will not help us in our case. This is not your fault, its mine. I did not fully wrote down our limitations. So here we are. We can't use branches or tag names as softwareswitches due to our project limitations. Is there a way to just call one job e.g. by using a ENV var or somethink like that inside a pipeline as a software switch? I'm familiar with other CI's and I have to say, gitlab ci is the worst I've ever seen due to many many limitations and unflexible configuration pattern.

Comment: Bounty started. =)

Answer (score 5):

Simply add a `when: manual` to the jobs you don't want to run.

These jobs will still appear in your pipeline but won't be run, unless someone "manually" starts them through the web interface, hence the name.

Here's more info about this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#when

If you're looking for something more "programmable", let's say run either `job1` or `job2` depending on a branch name or a tag, then you should have a look at the `only` and `except` keywords: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except

Comment: You could check my feedback @Ala answer if you like to.

Comment: Bounty started. =)

Answer (score 1):

The original question asks how to trigger jobs without using branch-names or tags. This leaves commit messages and environment variables as viable sources, and neither require editing your yaml file for each push.

## Commit Messages

Job rules with commit message regex is a very simple and flexible solution, in my experience.

1. Set up your .gitlab-ci.yml like this

```
job1:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: '
      $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /.*run job1.*/ ||
      $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /.*run all.*/
      '

job2:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: '
      $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /.*run job2.*/ ||
      $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /.*run all.*/
      '
```

2. Push with a commit message like this

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "testing conditional job triggers for gitlab-ci based on branch names and commit messages. run job1"
git push
```

You'll notice this also allows you to run both jobs with a message like this

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "testing all jobs. run all"
git push
```

## Environment Variables

Elsewhere in your answer to your own question you add a constraint: commit messages cannot be used. Environment variables can be set in the git cli

1. Set up your .gitlab-ci.yml like this

```
job1:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: $JOB1

job2:
  ...
  rules:
    - if: $JOB2
```

2. Push like this

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "triggering job1 with ci variables"
git push -o ci.variable="JOB1=anythingAtAll"
```

reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that provides a little flexibility using regular expressions comparing to job names:

```
variables:
    WHAT_TO_BUILD: '/^.*/'

.specific-job:
    rules:
        - if: $CI_JOB_NAME =~ $WHAT_TO_BUILD
          when: on_success
        - when: never


test_one:
    script:
        - echo "Test 1"
    extends:
        - .specific-job

test_two:
    script:
        - echo "Test 2"
    extends:
        - .specific-job

build_one:
    script:
        - echo "Build 1"
    extends:
        - .specific-job

build_two:
    script:
        - echo "Build 2"
    extends:
        - .specific-job
```

Pipelines can be triggered from the UI using CI/CD -> Pipelines -> Run pipeline, then set your variables as a regular express or exact job name.

Example usage:

- Default - runs everything
- WHAT_TO_BUILD = /^test.*/ - runs test_one and test_two
- WHAT_TO_BUILD = /^.*one/ - runs test_one and build_one
- WHAT_TO_BUILD = build_one - runs only build_one